# Why is one able to assign a list of child type to a list of its superclass type, in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have read topics on Generics and Wildcards in Kotlin and also their differences compared with Java, I have tried to search online, but I couldn't find the answer to this question nor make sure if anyone has asked it.

I've got the class `Note` and the class `FavouriteNote`, derived from the class `Note`. I've also got an array list with type parameter `Note` and an array list with type parameter `FavouriteNote`. I'm trying to assign `List<FavouriteNote>` to `List<Note>`, which of course won't work in Java.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
        List<FavouriteNote> favouriteNotes = new ArrayList<FavouriteNote>();

        notes = favouriteNotes; // this won't compile
    }
}


class Note {
    public final String name;

    public Note(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class FavouriteNote extends Note {
    public FavouriteNote(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

In Kotlin, though, I am free to assign `List<FavouriteNote>` to `List<Note>`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var notes = emptyList<Note>()
    val favouriteNotes = emptyList<FavouriteNote>()

    notes = favouriteNotes // compiles and runs successfully
}

open class Note(val name: String)

class FavouriteNote(name: String) : Note(name)
```

Why is that or what can I read to learn more about how this works in Kotlin and what is happening under the hood?

Comment: The simple answer is because Kotlin is awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the following examples, let's introduce one more class to use:

```java
class ShortNote extends Note {
    public ShortNote(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}
```

The biggest difference between Kotlin and Java generics is that Kotlin introduces *declaration site* variance for classes and interfaces. Java only has *use site* variance for classes and interfaces.

The variance of variable in Java can only be declared at the use site. If you don't specifically declare a List to be covariant, it is invariant:

```java
List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
List<FavouriteNote> favouriteNotes = new ArrayList<FavouriteNote>();
notes = favouriteNotes; // error
```

This is the type system preventing you from making a mistake. Suppose the above code didn't throw an error. Then this could happen:

```java
List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
List<FavouriteNote> favouriteNotes = new ArrayList<FavouriteNote>();
notes = favouriteNotes; // Invalid code, but pretend compiler allows it.
notes.add(new ShortNote("Hello")); // Permitted, a List<Note> is a Note consumer and
                                   // a ShortNote is a Note.
FavouriteNote aFavouriteNote = favouriteNotes.get(0); // ClassCastException!
```

Incidentally, Kotlin's MutableList does not make use of declaration site variance, so you would have the exact same restriction:

```kotlin
var notes: MutableList<Note> = ArrayList<Note>()
var favouriteNotes: MutableList<FavoriteNote> = ArrayList<FavoriteNote>()
notes = favouriteNotes // error
```

However, you can use use-site variance to make the cast possible. We can declare the list to be covariant at the use site:

```java
//Java
List<? extends Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
List<FavouriteNote> favouriteNotes = new ArrayList<FavouriteNote>();
notes = favouriteNotes; // OK
```

```kotlin
//Kotlin
var notes: MutableList<out Note> = ArrayList<Note>()
var favouriteNotes: MutableList<out FavoriteNote> = ArrayList<FavoriteNote>()
notes = favouriteNotes// OK
```

You are protected from the ClassCastException situation above because the compiler prevents you from adding items to a covariant list.

---

Now getting to declaration site variance. Kotlin declares the read-only List interface's type to be `<out T>` right in the definition of the interface. This means all Lists are automatically assumed to be covariant, even if you don't bother to declare it to be covariant at the use site.

If you declare variance at a class or interface's declaration site, the compiler will restrict you from making functions or properties that violate that variance. The read-only List interface doesn't have any `add` functions, so it is fine for it to be a `T` producer and not consumer.

Answer (score 3):

I believe mutability plays an important part. The java example doesn't work because `List`s are mutable, as in, you are able to add new elements to it. If it allowed the assignment and you would add a `Note` to `notes` you run into the problem that `favouriteNotes` would contain a non-`FavouriteNote` since it refers to the same list.

Kotlin's `emptyList` and `listOf` returns non-mutable lists. It allows the assignment because you can't add anything to `notes` anyway. Notice that if you change `notes`'s declaration as

```
var notes = mutableListOf<Note>()
```

you will run in the same compiler error as in Java